# Is there any online python exercise?

Tags: python

I am teaching a colleague Python and I think he should do some exercises.

Is there any online available other than python challenge?  I feel that python challenge is puzzles, not exercises.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is now also [Google's Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/), which includes lots of exercise.

Answer (score 16):

[Project Euler](http://www.projecteuler.net) is a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you are looking for, but I recommend the [O'Reilly School of Technology](http://www.oreillyschool.com/) [Beginning Python course](http://www.oreillyschool.com/courses/python1/).  This appears to be the first of four such courses, and though it is commercial, it's been good for me -- I've been using Python in anger for about two years, but have very little formal background programming.  This has been an excellent program that forces me to explore and become familiar with lots of parts of Python I was unaware of, and improving my coding ability and knowledge as well.

Answer (score 1):

there is [www.codecademy.com](http://codecademy.com)
it has some good exercise for beginners

Answer (score 0):

I use this:  http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python.html

Answer (score 0):

I just finished working through [Hacking Secret Ciphers with Python](http://inventwithpython.com/hacking/), available as a free PDF. The author supplies some foundation libraries, and then, through a series of chapters exploring some basic ciphers, introduces features of Python. He says he is using Python 3, but most of the features are common in 2.X as well.

If you want exercises, consider breaking out the expository material and assigning the cipher implementations as exercises.

Answer (score 0):

The computer science 101 course at http://udacity.com is a complete curriculum with lectures, problems, and quizzes, but you can jump right into the problem sets without needing to watch the lectures.

Answer (score -1):

How about [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html)?

(And for 3.x:  [Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.net))

Comment: He was asking for exercises.  At least in the Python 3 one, there basically aren't any.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/fall/) and [this](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc148h/winter/).

Those are courses taught at my University that use Python. I've used those assignments to demo/teach python to colleagues before

Comment: I think the OP wanted other online exercises besides the Python Challenge.